# pass a variable to an include through function

Tags: php

I want to pass variable to an including file through function. for example I have 2 files:
index.php:

```
<?php
$var = "this is a variable";
function get_template($template){
    require_once "theme/".$template;
}
get_template("index.php");
?>
```

than I have another file:
theme/index.php:

```
<?php
echo $var;
?>
```

How can I make $var global through function without writing global $var inside this function?

Comment: You can use the power of sessions.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, if the variable is within the scope of the function when the file is required, it will be within the scope of the required file. Try declaring a variable in your function and then `echo var_dump(get_defined_vars())` in the required file.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it in as a parameter to the function.  From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

```
$var = "this is a variable";
function get_template($template, $var){
    require_once "theme/".$template;
}
get_template("index.php", $var);
```

Comment: but there can be hundreds of variables. I can't write somehow just global $var in the index.php (not inside the theme/index.php).

Comment: Then make the parameter an array and put all of the variables you want inside of your template in that array

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
function get_template($template, array $args = array())
{
    extract($args);
    require_once "theme/".$template;
}

get_template("index.php", array('var' => 'this is a variable'));
```

But for the love of all that is holy, change your strategy.